# Can I show "dev tools" embedded in a page using Node Webkit (nw.js)?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm using `nw.js` (`node webkit`) and would like to show the web inspector (`dev tools`) embedded at the bottom of an html page.

Is this possible without adding an iframe to any page I want to do this?

[Here's the docs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#windowshowdevtoolsid--iframe-headless) that seem to only suggest doing this using an iframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [DevTools Jail Feature](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Devtools-jail-feature), you will see a demo function using the `headless` option. The callback (which is the same for `Window.showDevTools()`) provides a URL. It may be possible to utilize that URL to get the content (via AJAX), but there might be a limitation in functionality or some other serious concerns. Consider that if you use the devTools in a non-`<iframe>`, the markup for the devtools would actually be a part of your document making your devtools considerably slower and potentially subject to serious error.

Given that an `<iframe>` is customizable via HTML/CSS/ES(JS), and considering the above, I would carefully weigh the pros and potential cons before using anything other than an `<iframe>` or other `Window`.